# Insert HTML inside if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, append

I have list where I am inserting the image through jQuery.

```
$("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_u.png"  />');
```

This is my list

```
<ul>
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="one">
        <a href="#firstPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon1"></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" class="two">
        <a href="#secondPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon2"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have few navigation list like this. When each list is clicked, an 'active' class is called on.

My need is when I click the list, if the list has class 'active' then it should  append a html or else it should append another html.

This is my code below I tried but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.one').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_u.png" />');
        } else {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_c.png" />');
        }
    });
    $('li.two').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $("#icon2").html('<img src="images/audi_risk_u.png" />');
        } else {
            $("#icon2").html('<img src="images/audi_risk_c.png" />');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your click function ? Can you please add code for it ?

Comment: When I click on the list, I need to hightlight the image, for that I have made two images and called it through jQuery. I tried it in a way that if the list has 'active' class, display a image or else display another image.

Comment: @Anoopkinayath can you post your whole list items.

Comment: This is my code

         $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.one').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_u.png"  />');
        } else {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_c.png"  />');
        }
    });
  $('li.two').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $("#icon2").html('<img src="images/audi_risk_u.png"  />');
        } else {
           $("#icon2").html('<img src="images/audi_risk_c.png"  />');
        }
    });
});

Comment: List:

<li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="one"><a href="#firstPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon1"></a></li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" class="two"><a href="#secondPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon2"></a></li>

Comment: @Anoopkinayath you should use the `edit` button to update your answer with the code. I've done it for you in this case. I've also updated my answer for you as well.

Answer (score 8):

You need to put your code in to a click handler for the `li.one` element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.one').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_u.png" />');
        } else {
            $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_c.png" />');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you can also shorten this code by using a ternary expression:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.one').click(function() {
        $("#icon1").html('<img src="images/summary_icon_' + ($(this).hasClass('active') ? 'u' : 'c') + '.png" />');
    });
});
```

Now that you've added your current HTML and JS code I can see that you can DRY up the code with a single event handler which traverses the DOM from the current `li` to find the related `a` element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('a').html('<img src="images/summary_icon_' + ($(this).hasClass('active') ? 'u' : 'c') + '.png" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks. I have updated my code in jsfiddle, can you please have a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/6021py6o/

Answer (score 0):

As per your new requirement you can do this to store the icon source:

```
<ul>
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" 
        data-imgsrc="summary_icon_c.png" 
        data-active-imgsrc="summary_icon_u.png" class="one">
        <a href="#firstPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon1"></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" 
        data-imgsrc="audi_risk_c.png" 
        data-active-imgsrc="audi_risk_u.png" class="two">
        <a href="#secondPage" class="cmIcon" id="icon2"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can use attribute selectors `tag[attr]` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li[menuanchor]').click(function() {
        var src = $(this).hasClass('active') 
                  ? $(this).data('activeImgsrc') 
                  : $(this).data('imgsrc');
        $("a", this).html('<img src="images/'+ src +'" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Jai, I have different icons for each list

Comment: @Anoopkinayath that you can store with `data-src` attribute and use those. wait updating.

Comment: attribute selector code does not work . sorry.
Could you please check my code in the js fiddle.   https://jsfiddle.net/6021py6o/

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `active` class to current clicked `li`.

```
$('li > a').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass("active");
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active'); 
    }
});
```

Now it will add the class 'active' on click of that item and removes the class 'active' when you click on the same li again.